# making a local git repo clonable

Tags: git, git-clone

I have a local git repo. Now, I cannot upload the code on github, but the code is located on a machine which has a public IP. 
So, what do I need to do if I want to be able to clone the repo from a different machine.

thanks

Comment: `scp user@host:/var/github_repo ~/github_repo`.  Since it's not on github, no point in cloning. just copy the source.

Comment: It depends on which protocol is used from the other machine to the server that has a public IP. You need to provide this information.

Answer (score 3):

If the code is on a remote server, you can use `git clone`:

```
git clone ssh://user@host/var/local/git/repo.git
```

If the code is local, you can create a bare git repo on the remote and push your code. You can setup git to use your remote server as a "remote".  Then you can push/pull.

```
#on remote
cd /var/local/git
mkdir myrepo.git
cd myrepo.git
git init --bare

#on local
git remote add origin ssh://user@host/var/local/git/myrepo.git
git push -u origin master
```

That'll create a new repo on the remote, then use git push to push the code up to the remote server in a bare repo, which you can then use to clone to other machines using the above `git clone` command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the idea here is for you to use that machine as a remote. If you just want to move the repository from one machine to another, just use SCP as mentioned in [sircapsalot's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687714/making-a-local-git-repo-clonable#comment38280294_24687714).

Luckily, the book [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/) has a chapter on just this, setting up your own Git server.. I don't know what kind of protocol(s) you'd like to use, or what the setup is like, so I'll just link you directly to the chapter: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the repo from the same network/machine for code checkout. it should look something like this. ( add .git to the end of project location )

**//local_ip/location/project/.git** ( same lan )

or

**D:/Location/ProjectDirectory/.git** ( same machine )

```
git clone "//local_ip/location/project/.git" should work.
```

The same should work for Jenkins build job. Replace the git url with the above location.